# Grinding noise on my 2012 RAV4

Tags: toyota, noise, rav4

I hit a pothole and after driving about 10 minutes when I took my foot off the gas there was a grinding or rippling noise as it slowed down. The axle has been changed cause it was damaged but the grinding is still there

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

From your description, the wheel bearing could have been damaged and causing the noise. If you're feeling it more as a vibration, especially through the steering wheel, this is where I'd be looking. The wheel bearing can easily get damaged (unfortunately) from hitting a pothole hard or from a side impact to the tire/wheel.